# how to add order by date_created in a django loan history model

Tags: python, django

This the is model's code:

```python
class LoanInfoStatusHistory(models.Model):
    """Model that saves a history of a loan."""
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    loan = models.ForeignKey(Loan, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    previous_status = models.CharField(choices=Loan.LOAN_STATUS, max_length=20)
    new_status = models.CharField(choices=Loan.LOAN_STATUS, max_length=20)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        """
        Unicode representation for a LoanInfoStatusHistory model.
        :return: string
        """
        return '{}: {} - {}'.format(self.loan.id, self.previous_status, self.new_status)
```

Is there a way to configure that the items are ordered by the date and time they were created?

Comment: Please Elaborate your question.do you want to make a query to get results from database with order by date_created ?

Comment: Do you mean the day, the item was created, or updated? You've already defined an "update_date" field.

Comment: You don't have a `date_created` field on your model. Maybe you should rename `update_date` by `date_created` ?

Comment: class GetLoanRepaymentHistoryView(ListAPIView):
    """Get all loan repayment history."""
    serializer_class = LoanRepaymentSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, AdminDashboardPermission,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            loan = Loan.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('id'))
        except Loan.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'non_field_errors': ['Loan does not exist']}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        return LoanRepayment.objects.filter(loan=loan)

Comment: how can i add a query to get the date created loan history in asc order

Comment: Add a query where? In the model or in a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
class LoanInfoStatusHistory(models.Model):
    # other fields
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_created']
```